# How different problems with flutter 2 on some of my apps

Tags: flutter

I have several problems after updating to flutter 2 someone can help me solve them, I list the log below

**Flutter console error:**

```
    objc[88773]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both ??
    (0x1f9b08188) and ?? (0x113d382b8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[88773]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both ?? (0x1f9b081d8) and ??
    (0x113d38308). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    In file included from
    /Users/user/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences-0.4.3/ios/Classes/
    SharedPreferencesPlugin.m:5:
    /Users/user/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences-0.4.3/ios/Classes/
    SharedPreferencesPlugin.h:5:9: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
    #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Analyzing workspace
    note: Constructing build descriptionuser
```

Comment: If this happened after updating and you dont't have any custom code in your ios folder you can delete it and recreate it (with potentially updated flutter 2 code) running `flutter create .` inside the project.

Comment: i have try your soluton but

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I saw the same error when I ran flutter build ios.

The error message was displayed red color on my VS code terminal, but it was kind of misleading. I found it was not the main issue.

The actual issue should be on the following error section.

So, please run `flutter build ios --verbose` and read the output carefully.

In my situation, there were other issues of the failure of flutter build ios. The issues were like forget to put in GoogleService-Info.plist or iOS target version is less than the requirement of flutter packages.